# How to output a float neither in scientific, nor in fixed point notation in std::cout?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, floating-point

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float test = 12535104400;

    std::cout << test;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

//on msvc 2010 this ouputs:  1.25351e+010
```

I would like it to output just "12535104400" or in other words, the human readable format which has no leading zeros, but outputs the full value of a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The particular number cannot be accurately represented, for example try the following:

```
  float v = 12535104400;
  cout.precision(0);
  cout << fixed << v << endl;
```

You'll see it outputs: 12535104512

Comment: Thanks, I checked numeric_limits, and overlooked that 3.40282e+038 does not imply all intermediate values.

Comment: No matter what the encoding is, a type that takes up `n` bits of memory cannot encode more than `2**n` different values. This should have been your first warning sign, since 1e38 = 10 \*\* 38 > 2 \*\* 32 :)

Comment: Even worse, the literal `12535104400` is already outside the 2^32 range. Which, incidentally, means that this program relies on `long` being bigger than 32 bits, otherwise behavior is undefined. Undefined by the standard, that is - implementations with a `long long` type might well define the meaning of such a literal.

Comment: Actually, slight mistake - behavior is only undefined if `unsigned long` is exactly 34 bits, which I expect it isn't, anywhere. So normally it's either legal (if `long` is big enough) or ill-formed if it isn't, but if ill-formed it might compile anyway with implementation-specific results. The corner cases of integer literals in C and C++ are *ridiculous*.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to include `<iomanip>` :

```
int main()
{
    const double test = 12535104400;

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0) << test;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

- [`std::fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/) is the manipulator which uses fixed-point precision (not scientific notation)
- [`std::setprecision(0)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/) sets how many digits to display after the decimal point

Comment: thanks for the tip, this will only work for integers though, so if test would be only ever holding integers, that is the type it would be, and not float.

Comment: @ufotds Nope.  It definitely works for doubles, and I'm pretty sure it also works for floats.

Comment: @Maxpm: on my compiler it doesn't: 12.2 will output as 12 which does not meet my requirement of "but outputs the full value of a number"

Comment: I think ufotds's comment already explains the downvote. Your code prints "the full value of the number" if the number *happens* to be an integer, but doesn't print the full value of non-integers. OK, so it's unclear from the question whether the solution needs to work for non-integer values, but a comment from the questioner disambiguates.

Answer (score 3):

`float test = 12535104400;`

This should be a compiler error if your compiler doesn't support `long long` and int is 32-bit. Use floating literals instead of integer literals e.g `1234.0f` vs `1234`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    float test = 12535104400.0f;

    std::cout << std::setiosflags(ios::fixed) << std::setprecision(0) << test;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

should print what you want. But beware that float isn't that precise

Comment: 1234.0 is a double literal not a float literal, hence float test = 12535104400.0 should generate a compiler warning. 1234.0f is a float.

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck, 4-byte float can store cca 7 digits. Use double or long for such numbers.

Comment: Actually using a double leads to the exact same output, which is by the way the correct value, which makes me assume that the variable can hold it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In order to format the output in `iostream`, you'll need [manipulators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to lose precision, you can typecast it to an integer.

`cout << int(test);`

or

`cout << (int)test;`

Comment: "The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be
represented in the destination type." (4.9/1).